# Cannot go to different endpoint using apache Tomcat

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, tomcat, web

Im learning spring boot and am currently deploying pages with intellij, the course im doing uses eclipse with apache Tomcat. I have set up my server and can get my home page up. However if I want to go to a different endpoint its giving me a 404.

This is my home page

```
package com.luv2code.springdemo.mvc;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String showPage(){
        return "main-menu";
    }
}
```

And this is the page id like to get to

```
package com.luv2code.springdemo.mvc;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class HelloWorldController {

    // need a controller method to show the initial HTML form
    @RequestMapping("/showForm")
    public String showForm() {
        return "Helloworld-form";
    }
    //need a controller method to process the HTML form
}
```

Here is my Tomcat server that is successful and deploys.
[Tomcat server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxrJv.png)

Yet when I try to go to another page it gives me this error
[404 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PByNT.png)

Any help as to why its doing this would be great and how to fix it thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to create JSP pages for the corresponding mappings. When you are returning `return "Helloworld-form"` from `showForm()` of `HelloWorldController` class, spring actually is looking for the JSP by that name.
Create JSPs by that name should resolve your issue